# Asynchronous Web site

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asynchronous, user-controls, master-pages

I have a website that has 8 web parts and a user control. The page takes a really long time to load (>10s). The problem manly is the user control. What is the best choice to make this web asynchronous. I looked into jQuery's ajax and also Update panels but im not sure if that's the best choice. The web page has a master page and a content page.

The content page has this div inside:

```
<div id="courseTree" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" style="border:0;padding:0;width:340px; height: auto; overflow:visible; display:block; float:left;">
        <CoursesEnglish:TreeEnglish runat="server"/>            
    </div>
```

The user control has two files, an .ascx.cs and an .ascx. The ascx makes a request to the .cs that returns a stringbuilder with all the necessary info and tags etc...

The user control method that makes the calling looks like this :

```
<div id="MyCourses" class="LIUBox" style="width: 300px;">
        <div id="UCTreeCourses" class="LIUBox Header" style="padding-bottom: 6px;">
            My Courses
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="accordion2" class="LIU_accordion">
                <%= getMyCoursesScript() %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to know if i should be using jQuery or update panels or something entirely different. What I want to accomplish is that the page loads the master page, and all web parts and user control are in blank, then when its loaded, the webparts and the user control start loading. Thanks

Comment: I would first figure out what part is taking 10 seconds and figure out why it is taking 10 seconds. That's a *really* long time for just getting data.

Comment: Its the query made by the "getMyCoursesScript()" method, unfortunately i cant change those queries at this time. Not because I dont want to but because I yet lack the knowledge.

Comment: Well, making all of this asynchronous is probably going to be pretty involved too, and won't really make everything all of a sudden faster. It will still take 10 seconds + the time it takes to get everything else to get the courses.

Comment: Do something entirely different - use cache ! Render your control before you need to show up, saved it on cache, and just show the rendered cache

Comment: Well, i've seen pages like for example, http://www.as.com, if you look at it closely you will see that the banners and css, js, are all loaded first. After loading that, it starts loading all the images that the page has

Comment: From what I understand, if you load all the skeleton of the web page first and after the page is load, you load the remainder parts, it will feel faster since it doesnt load the page ALL at once